# zeep.exceptions.Fault: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: soap, wsdl, zeep

I'm trying to send request and receive the response of a soap service using the python package `zeep`.
But I can't do this, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oussama/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    res = client.service.addShip(**data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 51, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 135, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 229, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 333, in process_error
    detail=fault_node.find("detail"),
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my code:

```py
import zeep
client = zeep.Client(wsdl='http://track.smsaexpress.com/SECOM/SMSAwebService.asmx?WSDL')
data = {
    'passKey': 'xxxxxxx',
    'refNo': None,
    'sentDate': None,
    'idNo': None,
    'cName': None,
    'cntry': None,
    'cCity': None,
    'cZip': None,
    'cPOBox': None,
    'cMobile': None,
    'cTel1': None,
    'cTel2': None,
    'cAddr1': None,
    'cAddr2': None,
    'shipType': None,
    'PCs': 1,
    'cEmail': None,
    'carrValue': None,
    'carrCurr': None,
    'codAmt': None,
    'weight': None,
    'custVal': None,
    'custCurr': None,
    'insrAmt': None,
    'insrCurr': None,
    'itemDesc': None,
    'sName': None,
    'sContact': None,
    'sAddr1': None,
    'sAddr2': None,
    'sCity': None,
    'sPhone': None,
    'sCntry': None,
    'prefDelvDate': None,
    'gpsPoints': None,
}

res = client.service.addShip(**data)
print(res)
```

Here ([Link](http://track.smsaexpress.com/SECOM/SMSAwebService.asmx?WSDL#folder9)) you can find some info about the service

Answer (score 1):

The zeep Client object is looking for a string and does not like the **None** keyword.  Change the None to "" or '' (i.e. string space) and you should be good to go.

```
import zeep
client = zeep.Client(wsdl='http://track.smsaexpress.com/SECOM/SMSAwebService.asmx?WSDL')
data = {
    'passKey': 'xxxxxxx',
    'refNo': "",
    'sentDate': "",
    'idNo': "",
    'cName': "",
    'cntry': "",
    'cCity': "",
    'cZip': "",
    'cPOBox': "",
    'cMobile': "",
    'cTel1': "",
    'cTel2': "",
    'cAddr1': "",
    'cAddr2': "",
    'shipType': "",
    'PCs': 1,
    'cEmail': "",
    'carrValue': "",
    'carrCurr': "",
    'codAmt': "",
    'weight': "",
    'custVal': "",
    'custCurr': "",
    'insrAmt': "",
    'insrCurr': "",
    'itemDesc': "",
    'sName': "",
    'sContact': "",
    'sAddr1': "",
    'sAddr2': "",
    'sCity': "",
    'sPhone': "",
    'sCntry': "",
    'prefDelvDate': "",
    'gpsPoints': "",
}

res = client.service.addShip(**data)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition from the wsdl differs from the implementation on the server side. if you change the request that all optional fields contain a valid value it will return a result stating that the passKey is incorrect.

If you use a mock tool like SoapUI that mocks the server side it is perfectly fine to send a request with the dictionary looking like this

```
data = {'PCs' : 1}
```

In a side node the wsdl has both soap1.1 and soap1.2 implemented if you mock it make sure you use the correct endpoint url otherwise you keep sending data to the original server.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I haven't any idea about mocking and I don't know if I can solve this issue using it.

Comment: With mocking tools you are able to test your code to make sure you meet all the requirements that the actual server needs. This will help you understand how the server works and which questions you can ask to the owner of the server. in this case you can ask the owner which elements are required to send your request as the wsdl states only the PCs is manditory but the call fails when the other elements are left out.